# How to play an embedded sound in a PDF on Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, pdf, adobe, adobe-reader, okular

I've been trying to play the embedded sounds that are in a PDF document. I have tried installing the latest Adobe Reader released for Ubuntu and I also installed the Okular but none of these readers work.
What should I do? When I open the pdf file on Okular and I double-click on the sound icon, it pops out the name of the audio file in a yellow note, but no sound is played.